# Duplicate Entries with multi Union

Tags: mysql, union, distinct

I have this

```
               (SELECT  DISTINCT '1' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '2' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'da silva dias'  AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '3' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND sobrenome      REGEXP 'da silva dias'   AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '4' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND sobrenome      REGEXP 'silva dias'      AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '5' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'silva dias'     AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '6' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '7' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '8' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION DISTINCT (SELECT  DISTINCT '9' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND tipo <> '7')   ORDER BY sb
```

### The result:

2 - leidiana da silva dias
3 - leidiana da silva dias
4 - leidiana da silva dias
5 - leidiana da silva dias
6 - leidiana da silva dias

### 7 - leidiana da silva dias

As you can see I tried to solve the problem and ended up putting everything into distinct. rs

Answer (score 1):

You are forcing the results across the unions to be distinct with the first column (`sb`). You could probably solve the problem with an outer `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT min(sb) AS sb, name, id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol
FROM (
      (SELECT  '1' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '2' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'da silva dias'  AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '3' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND sobrenome      REGEXP 'da silva dias'   AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '4' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND sobrenome      REGEXP 'silva dias'      AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '5' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'silva dias'     AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '6' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '7' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE nome          REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '8' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'leidiana'       AND tipo <> '7') 
UNION (SELECT  '9' as sb,nome,id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol FROM usuarios WHERE sobrenome     REGEXP 'leidiana da'    AND tipo <> '7')) sbs
GROUP BY name, id,sobrenome,nasc,genero,escol
ORDER BY sb
```